# Quando usar AsSplitQuery() no EF Core?

Tags: query, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Em uma determinada consulta sendo ela 1 para N, ou seja "um para muitos" a [documentação da Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/ef/core/querying/single-split-queries) recomenda dividir a consulta utilizando `AsSplitQuery()` ou realizando a configuração globalmente a fim de evitar problemas de performance.

Porém, podemos observar que no final do artigo, é apresentado alguns pontos negativos dessa abordagem, principalmente:

> Cada consulta atualmente implica um ida e volta de rede adicional para seu banco de dados. Várias viagens de ida e volta de rede podem prejudicar o desempenho, especialmente onde a latência para o banco de dados é alta (por exemplo, serviços de nuvem).

Então fiz um teste, realizando uma consulta com o operador `AsSplitQuery()` e sem o operador, e para minha surpresa, a consulta sem o operador foi 10ms mais rápida.

Então, me pergunto:

- Devemos realmente sempre usar o argumento `AsSplitQuery()`?
- Quando usar?
- Quando não usar?

Abaixo trago detalhes do meu desenvolvimento:

- Model's

```
    public class SuportRequests
    {
        [Key]
        public int? Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public StatusEnum Status { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime DataCad { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public CriticidadeEnum Criticidade { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Solicitante { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public TipoEnum Tipo { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Descricao { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public bool Prioritario { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public AtividadesEnum DesempAtividades { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Titulo { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string CnpjEmpresa { get; set; }

        public IList Mensagens { get; set; }

        public IList Anexos { get; set; }

        public DateTime DataAtendimento { get; set; }

        public DateTime DataAtendimentoFim { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    public class SuportRequestsFiles
    {    
        [Key]
        public string FileName { get; set; }

        public string RandomFileName { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateModificacao { get; set; }

        public int Tamanho { get; set; }

        public string Tipo { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [ForeignKey("Suport")]
        public int IdMensagem { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public SuportRequests Suport { get; set; }
    }
```

- Consulta gerada SEM `AsSplitQuery()`

```
SELECT `s`.`Id`, `s`.`CnpjEmpresa`, `s`.`Criticidade`, `s`.`DataAtendimento`, `s`.`DataAtendimentoFim`, `s`.`DataCad`, `s`.`Descricao`, `s`.`DesempAtividades`, `s`.`Prioritario`, `s`.`Solicitante`, `s`.`Status`, `s`.`Tipo`, `s`.`Titulo`, `s0`.`FileName`, `s0`.`IdMensagem`, `s0`.`DateModificacao`, `s0`.`RandomFileName`, `s0`.`Tamanho`, `s0`.`Tipo`
FROM `Suport` AS `s`
LEFT JOIN `SuportFiles` AS `s0` ON `s`.`Id` = `s0`.`IdMensagem`
ORDER BY `s`.`Id`, `s0`.`FileName`
```

- Consulta gerada COM `AsSplitQuery()`

```
SELECT `s`.`Id`, `s`.`CnpjEmpresa`, `s`.`Criticidade`, `s`.`DataAtendimento`, `s`.`DataAtendimentoFim`, `s`.`DataCad`, `s`.`Descricao`, `s`.`DesempAtividades`, `s`.`Prioritario`, `s`.`Solicitante`, `s`.`Status`, `s`.`Tipo`, `s`.`Titulo`
FROM `Suport` AS `s`
ORDER BY `s`.`Id`
```

```
SELECT `s0`.`FileName`, `s0`.`IdMensagem`, `s0`.`DateModificacao`, `s0`.`RandomFileName`, `s0`.`Tamanho`, `s0`.`Tipo`, `s`.`Id`
FROM `Suport` AS `s`
INNER JOIN `SuportFiles` AS `s0` ON `s`.`Id` = `s0`.`IdMensagem`
ORDER BY `s`.`Id`
```

Podemos verificar que o argumento `AsSplitQuery()` gera duas consultas, consequentemente gerando dois eventos de I.O no banco de dados.

Porém o questionamento ainda continua, é benéfico ou o argumento `AsSplitQuery()` deve ser usado com cuidado?

Comment: isso é tudo muito vago, é preciso ver a query no banco, o *execution plain*, index, etc... não existe uma pergunta unica, depende de muitas coisas.. chegou a analisar as duas queries com as ferramentas de análise do banco para entender a diferença?

Comment: @RicardoPontual vou fazer uma atualização na perguntando, colocando os models e os dois tipos de consulta que obtive como retorno. Não cheguei a analisar com ferramentas de banco de dados mas avaliei elas no output do visual studio.

Comment: boa, com a estrutura da pra ter uma ideia melhor :)

Answer (score 0):

O objetivo do `AsSplitQuery()` é evitar a chamada **explosão cartesiana**.

Explico:

Imagine o seguinte cenário: 1 universidade possuí *N* professores e *M* alunos .

Faríamos a seguinte query no EF Core:

```
DbSet<Universidade>()
.Include(t => t.Professores)
.Include(t => t.Alunos)
.ToList();
```

Vamos assumir que a universidade tenha 20 professores (*N*) e 600 alunos (*M*).

O cálculo para descobrir quantas linhas (rows) vamos retornar do banco é `1 x N x M` -> `1 * 20 * 600 = 12000`

Aí você pergunta: *como isso é possível? Como um join com 20 registros e outro com 600 podem virar 12000?*

A resposta está em como bancos de dados relacionais funcionam: **joins em bancos relacionais produzem produtos cartesianos**.

Exemplo:

1 universidade fazendo join com 3 professores e 5 alunos

u - universidade |
p - professor |
a - aluno

```
{u} x {p1, p2, p3} x {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5} = 
{up1a1, up1a2, up1a3, up1a4, up1a5, 
up2a1, up2a2, up2a3, up2a4, up2a5, 
up3a1, up3a2, up3a3, up3a4, up3a5}
```

Você percebe que toda vez que faz um join `one-to-many` a entidade principal fica repetida? Isso é a explosão cartesiana.

O `AsSplitQuery()` evita esse comportamento rodando essas queries separadamente, então ao invés de `1 * N * M` você tem `1 + N + M` que no nosso caso seria `1 + 20 + 600 = 621`. Bem melhor que as 12000 linhas.

```
DbSet<Universidade>()
.Include(t => t.Professores)
.Include(t => t.Alunos)
.AsSplitQuery()
.ToList();
```

"*Mas minha query foi mais rápida sem o `AsSplitQuery`!*"

No seu exemplo especifico, você tem 1 `support` com *N* `SupportFiles`.

O cálculo sem o `AsSplitQuery` seria `1 * N` e o cálculo com o `AsSplitQuery` seria `1 + N`.

Vamos supor que 1 `Support` tenha 10 `SupportFiles`

Sem o `AsSplitQuery` - `1 * 10 = 10` - 1 ida ao banco.

Com o `AsSplitQuery` - `1 + 10 = 11` - 2 idas ao banco.

Então, nesse caso, a utilização do `AsSplitQuery` é maléfica, pois além de bater uma outra vez no banco, é trazido 1 registro a mais do que quando não utilizamos o `AsSplitQuery`.

"Existe um cenário onde um simples *one-to-many*, igual ao exemplo acima, se beneficiaria do `AsSplitQuery`?"

Sim, existe. Lembra que eu comentei que num join, a entidade principal se repete pela quantidade de registros do join? Imagine que a entidade principal, nessse caso, `Support`, tenha colunas muito grandes, com textos enormes ou `blobs` (arquivos binários). O join vai repetir essa entidade principal N vezes, e fazer essas colunas pesadas e repetidas serem trafegadas pela rede, podendo aumentar o tempo pra fazer o download da resposta do banco. Nesse caso, usar o `AsSplitQuery` e retornar 1 `Support` numa chamada e depois + 10 `SupportFiles` *poderia* ser benéfico.

Mas, lembre-se: se tratando de performance, suposições e opiniões não contam; medições sim.